# Why use a resistor in filter circuits

Tags: resistors, filter

Since capacitors and inductors can filter on their own. Why are separate resistors needed? For example in a RC circuit, using only a capacitor would be different in what manner?

Comment: What is the RC constant if R is zero? If R is infinite?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Since capacitors and inductors can filter on their own.

Consider the following "filter" consisting of a capacitor *on its own*:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSXhFy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that, by inspection, \$V_{out} = V_{in}\$ regardless of the presence of the capacitor; there is no filtering taking place.

This is because the output port is *identical* to the input port.

Now, add a resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9URNv.png)</sup>

Note that we now have distinct input and output ports and now we have a 1st order filter.  We could have added in inductor instead of a resistor and created a 2nd order filter.

$$V_{out}= V_{in}\frac{1}{1+j\omega C_1 R_1}$$

Comment: Although, if the signal source (Vin) is nonideal, it might not be able to sustain the desired voltage in the presence of a capacitor to ground due its output impedance/internal resistance.

For example, consider page 4 of [this datasheet for the lm4549b](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4549b.pdf).  Look at the Zout for the analog output section.   Lets say that we are driving a 16KHz 1Vpp audio signal from the output.

 If I stuck a capacitor on the output to ground, would it be reasonable to say that I've formed an RC filter with the 220 Ohms out output impedance from this "Vin"?

Comment: @jjmilburn, you're not thinking clearly.  The voltage \$V_{in}\$ is the voltage across the input port *period*.  If the source \$V_s\$ is ideal, then \$V_{in} = V_s\$.  If the source is not ideal, i.e., if the source has some internal impedance, then \$V_{in} \ne V_s\$ **BUT**, the transfer function \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$, is unchanged.  Instead, it is \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_s}\$ that is changed.

Comment: Ah yes, good catch and clarification.

Answer (score 6):

On their own, a capacitor or an inductor is just a simple single-port component. Filters, on the other hand have an input and an output meaning they are two-port devices.

To get a simple two port filter you can use combinations of resistors, capacitors and inductors to create various filter types such as high pass and low-pass. Using more than one of each can get you band-pass and notch filter (band reject filter).

Using a resistor and a capacitor/inductor you can get 1st order filters. Using capacitors and inductors can get you 2nd order filters. 2nd order filters have a more pronounced filtering characteristic.

If you had a single resistor you cannot call it an attenuator - two resistors are needed in series to create an attenuator; a simple two wire component transforms into a more complex three-wire device with an input, an output and a common connection i.e. a two-port network.

Answer (score 5):

No, inductors and capacitors don't filter "on their own".

For example, a capacitor in series with a signal performs no filtering if the impedance at the other end is infinite.  Likewise, a capacitor accross a signal voltage performs no filtering if the impedance of that voltage is zero.

Show a circuit where you think a capacitor is doing filtering on its own.  After looking carefully, we will find some impedance somewhere it is working against to make the high pass or low pass filter.

Using a explicit resistor with a capacitor or inductor, rather than letting it work against stray, implied, or internal impedance, helps make things predictable.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should have left it strictly theoretical, or mention that you will always have a filter-like effect because there will always be some R in the real world.  Well said.

Comment: @Olin Lanthrop Could you explain the impedance part a little more? Can I think of it as resistance in series or parallel?

Comment: @1p2r: Resistance can be either in parallel or in series with either inductors or capacitors, depending on how the filter is connected in the circuit and whether it is supposed to be high pass or low pass.  However, this hand waving is just feeding the confusion.  Show a schematic so that we have something concrete to talk about.

Comment: @Olin I was reffering to the second paragraph, where you mention impedance at the other end and impedance of a voltage.

Comment: I think a simple way to understand why a capacitor-only filter can't work is to first think why a resistor-only filter won't work: the voltage at any non-driven node in a resistor network will be a linear function of the voltages at any driven nodes.  As it happens, any network consisting of only ideal caps or only ideal inductors will work the same way.  The effective impedance of a cap or inductor will very with frequency, but every cap will vary exactly the same way, as will every inductor.  In a network consisting of only caps and inductors...

Comment: ...which is driven with any one particular fixed frequency, the voltage at every node will be a linear function of the voltages at all the driven nodes, but since inductors and caps vary differently with frequency, the set of linear functions at each frequency will be different.

Comment: @OlinLathrop single inductor and capacitor filters [link](http://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/02116.png) and [link](http://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/02118.png) first one low pass second one high pass. they are taken from [link](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_2/chpt_8/2.html)

Comment: @1p2r: Huh!!?  Those links both clearly show a resistor together with the capacitor or inductor.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The resistor is the load that is accepting the signal at its inputs. In comparison to this [link](http://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/02117.png) that filters with 2 components. To quote from the same page "The inductive low-pass filter is the pinnacle of simplicity, with only one component comprising the filter. The capacitive version of this filter is not that much more complex, with only a resistor and capacitor needed for operation. However, despite their increased complexity, capacitive filter designs are generally preferred over inductive because capacitors tend to be..."

Answer (score 2):

Because, without the resistor, the energy this circuit could output would be infinite and not at all depended on the capacitor.

Think about it this way:

If there was no capacitor then there would be zero resistance between \$Vin\$ and \$Vout\$. Zero resistance means that infinite current would flow between \$Vin\$ and \$Vout\$ (remeber that \$Vin\$ is an ideal voltage source and therefore is capable of doing stuff like providing a circuit with infinite energy) which means that \$Vout\$ will always be equal to \$Vin\$ (because an electric potential can not form between them, electrons flow totally free).

Your circuit fills up with infinite energy in the form of this infinite current and it does not matter what happens with the capacitor (which can not leak any energy anyway as current can not pass through a capacitor), your output will always be what you want it to be (up to infinity) while \$Vin\$ is positive.
If you add the resistor what happens is that you create a potential between \$Vout\$ and \$Vin\$ and \$Vout\$ and the "top" end of the capacitor. Current can no longer flow in infinite amounts and the following sequence of events happens:

The capacitor starts to fill up on the "top" end (remember that without the resistor this would have happened instantly, providing you with a "gap-less" source of current at \$Vout\$).

While it fills up on the "top" end, the electrons stored in that end will start to "pull" up electrons from the ground into the "bottom" end. This "moves" energy from the "top" end to the "bottom" end. This either happens until the capacitor is full or until the \$Vin\$ potential reverses, this is why both R (the amount of current per time that fills the capacitor) and C (how much the capacitor can hold) both matter when analyzing the filter.

If the capacitor gets full before the potential at \$Vin\$ reverses (this happens if the frequency is "slower" than the capacitor is "big"), then no more current flows into it and all the remaining current flows towards \$Vout\$.

If the potential reverses at \$Vin\$ before the capacitor gets full (the "frequency" is faster than the capacitor is "big") then all the current flows back into \$Vin\$ as \$Vin\$ is now in a lower potential than ground. In this case the energy in the "bottom" end of the capacitor moves back to ground as there is not more charge at the "top" end to keep it in the capactitor. This means that energy transfered from the "top" to the "bottom" end now gets transfered to ground (and is for all practical purposes, lost).

Answer (score 1):

In a very theoretical sense, if e.g. a capacitor existed as a filter, the time constant would be \$R*C\$, and with \$R = 0\$, the time constant would be 0.

\$R\$ sets the time constant and the corner frequency/-3dB point in filters.

Note:edited per Andy aka's suggestions/advice.

Comment: The bigger the frequency the less the attenuation for a capacitor, right? But doesn't the cap value also affect the attenuation? Wouldn't it be possible to set the parameters with just the capacity value?

Comment: Look at the math: in a "perfect" capacitor and inductor (which don't exist, but I'm talking theory here) R = 0, so the math goes to infinity or 0.  There is no setting anything, because you already set one parameter to 0, so even a very very large C, when multiplied by 0, is still 0, and a very tiny L, when divided by 0, goes to infinity.

Comment: @Bob an inductor (with or without a resistor) will not block all ac signals unless its inductance were infinite. Similarly, a capacitor won't be a dead short for all ac signals unless it was infinite.

Comment: @Andy aka, I'm trying to think that one through, and I'm not sure you're correct. If you modeled e.g. an RL circuit, and assumed all R = 0 (including the internal resistance of a real world inductor = 0), even a tiny inductance would be the only thing on the circuit other than the signal source.  It's so theoretical and kind of a corner case that I haven't thought about since college, but you'd have to provide me with a frequency response equation that had something other than f = 0 or infinity with R = 0 to convince me I'm wrong...

Comment: @Bob the impedance of an inductor is \$|wL|\$. If L = 0.1H and w is 1000 then impedance is 100 ohms. Same sort of argument for capacitors; impedance is \$\frac{1}{|wc|}\$

Comment: @Andy aka: Right, so if there are no R's, it's like a circuit with only one resistor: even a small resistor carries all the voltage it is in parallel with, even if it is a pico-ohm, simply because there is nothing else in the circuit, just like the inductor will block all AC and pass all DC if you just consider L.  Are you talking about higher than first order?  In something higher than first order, you have an excellent point.  Given the question, I figured we were talking first order...

Comment: @Bob - I'm not talking about higher orders; I'm just talking about an inductor or capacitor having an impedance dependent on frequency and unless they are infinite in value i.e. infinite henries or infinite farads then they do not block/unblock any frequency.

Comment: @Andy aka, I agree with you.  Given the simplicity of the question, I was talking about "if you have an inductor with no R, it does this, and if you have a capacitor with no R, it does that, and that's why we need R in our design".  Of course, as soon as you put a load on anything, you place an R somewhere in the circuit, and you get what you are talking about; but then there's an R and it doesn't satisfy the question any more.  So, as a very simple way of putting it, C passes AC,L blocks AC,and R allows you to set a corner frequency. I'm giving some intuition while answering a simple question

Comment: @Bob I'm giving you a chance to correct your answer. Yes it is a simplistic question but that is no-reason to answer simplistically; it is wrong to say "an inductor would pass all DC perfectly and block all AC signals".

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the math:
\$ \ I = \ C  \frac {dv}{dt} \$
and assuming a sinusoidal input voltage,
\$ \ V = A \sin \omega t\$
then the Current \$ \ I \$ that would follow in the capacitor circuit, will be: \$ \ I = \ C \frac {d {A \sin \omega t}}{dt}  \$
and so \$ \ I \$  will equal: \$ \ I = \omega\ C \ * \ A \cos \omega t \$

this last equation says that if we would measure the current following in the capacitor circuit,
we would see a sinusoidal current with an amplitude of  \$ \omega\ C \ * \ A \$ that changes with the changes in the frequency of the input voltage, but the amplitude of the output voltage will always be the same as the input voltage regardless of any changes that happens in the frequency of the input voltage.

Comment: This is the answer to which question?